# Which are the advantages of the Spring Session compared with Servlet HttpSession?

Tags: java, spring-session, httpsession

1. Which are the advantages of the Spring Session compared with Servlet HttpSession?
2. Where should I use the Spring session?

Answer (score 1):

**HttpSession**

> Provides a way to identify a user across more than one page request or visit to a Web site and to store information about that user. The servlet container uses this interface to create a session between
> an HTTP client and an HTTP server. The session persists for a
> specified time period, across more than one connection or page request
> from the user. A session usually corresponds to one user, who may
> visit a site many times. The server can maintain a session in many
> ways such as using cookies or rewriting URLs.

[More Info](http://www.servlets.com/javadoc/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html)

---

---

**Spring Session**

> Spring Session provides a transparent approach to resolving the
> limitations of the HTTP session. It provides central session
> management without being tied to container-specific solutions (e.g
> Tomcat, Jetty etc.)...

> Traditionally HTTPSession is container-specific i.e the container will
> create a session and provide the session ID to the application. This
> essentially means that if our application is running on a clustering
> environment, each container will have its own HTTPSession management.
> Session information is not shared across the different servers. The
> session-id generated by application server 1 will be unknown to the
> second application server.

[More Info](https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring/spring-session/)

> Spring Session provides transparent integration with HttpSession. This
> means that developers can switch the HttpSession implementation out
> with an implementation that is backed by Spring Session.

[More Info](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/2.2.x/reference/html/httpsession.html)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Spring Session do more advanced things than Tomcat HttpSession. HttpSession it's used in Servlets and Spring Session can be used in Servlets, RestApi...

Ex:
[Why Spring Session and HttpSession](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/http-session.html#httpsession-why)

Answer (score 1):

HttpSession actually is limited to a certain web container, which means its lifecycles are maintained by a container like Tomcat/Jetty. But when you have a couple of servers (normally a reverse agency like Nginx + several server instances), each server would have its own session, so a user will have to login more than once when successive requests hit different servers (e.g. Server A for the 1st time and server B for the 2nd time).

Keys to address this problem include:

1.Sync session informations among all server instances or

2.Maintain a global session

Actually Spring session aims at the 2nd solution, providing a global session management framework while supporting extensions with different 3rd-party persistence libraries like Redis/JDBC/In Memory.

Theoretically syncing sessions by yourself is also ok, but hard to maintain and time-consuming.